# Over riding sys.excepthook

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I am trying to design a package which has **init**.py and multiple sub modules and each module has multiple classes defined in it. 
I used python's logging library to create logs. 
I want to log any uncaught error to my log file, that may arise when program executes.
I understand overriding sys.excepthook is used to achieve this. So I inserted the following code into all my sub modules at the top after logger definition for that module

```
def handle_exception(exc_type,exc_value,exc_traceback,logger=logger):
     logger.error("Uncaught exception", exc_info=(exc_type, exc_value,
```

`sys.excepthook = handle_exception`

But this seems to not solve the problem because RuntimeErrors are still being displayed to console and not logged into the file.

What am I doing wrong here ?